# Java (JDK1.8) is not setting server_name extension in SSL handshake when hostname has '_'

Tags: java, ssl, https, java-8

```
CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
System.out.println(httpclient.execute(httpget));
```

I am using this programming snippet and using this with couple of urls. "https://abc.def.com/file.txt" and "https://ab_c.def.com/file.txt" (actual names i used exist - this is just an example). When i run the code with -Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake:data options set, I see _**server_name**_ extension is added only in case of abc.def.com and not in case of ab_c.def.com.

I am aware that java.net.URL package doesn't allow '_' in hostname. Is this a similar issue? Is there any workaround to get the SSL handshake include the hostname with '_'?

Comment: `_` is not a valid character in an hostname and hence in the hostname part of an URL. It can be in a DNS record when it is in a "domain name" (using RFC 1034 terms), like a CNAME or a SRV. But by definition in URLs you have hostnames and an hostname is only letters, digits or hyphens (plus some extra rules on top of that)

Comment: See [Restrictions on valid hostnames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_hostnames)

Comment: agree. But there are hosts that use '_', so looking to see if there are any workarounds.

Comment: One workaround is to refuse to talk to those sites.  If they choose to ignore the standards, make it not your problem.

Comment: It is worth noting that this can apparently crash the JVM in some contexts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51490625/jvm-crashes-using-underline-as-part-of-sni-server-name.  But that might be netty native code crashing.  Hard to say.

Comment: Force setting to a name with '_' throws an exception `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Contains non-LDH ASCII characters
 at java.net.IDN.toASCIIInternal(IDN.java:296)
 at java.net.IDN.toASCII(IDN.java:122)
 at javax.net.ssl.SNIHostName.<init>(SNIHostName.java:99)`

Comment: Is it perhaps somehow related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2222519/url-encoding-with-underscores-in-a-directory-name/2222555

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no. This wont work in java using the standard JDK libraries with HTTPS.

There virtually no "normal" Java way to work around this problem. 
Other ideas:

- ask the service owner to provide a domain name without the `_`.
- dont use SSL/HTTPS. Most Java HTTP clients that are not doing strict checks will work with a hostname with an underscore in it. This is not a great solution if you are on the open internet
- do use HTTPS but go direct to the IP address and disable HTTPS hostname validation. This is also a bad idea if you are on the open internet
- introduce a MITM or forward proxy that can provide a HTTP endpoint to your service, but will do HTTPS over the untrusted parts of the network, (SSL onloading?)
- just shell out to `curl` and read the resulting string, as described [here on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/java-curl). Be very careful here, as it's very easy to unwittingly open yourself up security issues like remote code execution
- use jni to get to a network library that will allow the underscore - `libcurl` is an obvious candidate, but this will be significantly more work than the `System.execute` method, also possibly unsafe for other reasons (memory management, instability of badly written jni interop, not great for maintainability)
- You could possibly try to fork the related URI / URL parsing classes in `java.net` to remove the check for the underscore. The problem with this is it's a massive hack, possibly of unbounded difficulty, could easily break all manner of things unintentionally and you might need to build your own version of the JDK as I have some recollection of `java.net` code being special for some reason in that you couldn't just chuck a patched class in ext/lib dir of the JVM (but I could be mixing that up with something else).

Comment: *dont use SSL/HTTPS.* and *do use HTTPS but go direct to the IP address and disable HTTPS hostname validation.*  won't work if the server is a virtual server that shares the IP address with other servers with different hostnames.  Such a configuration requires the use of HTTPS with SNI to identify the server instance .

Comment: yes I did try both the options. I1) server did a redirect to https and 2) the server rejected the request with IP address in SNI.

Comment: offloading it to curl was the one i chose.

Answer (score 0):

I will provide a hotfix.

In your /etc/hosts file, include a new entry without the underscore to the IP.

For example,

abc.com xx.xx.xx.xx

Then, use abc.com in your program.

Comment: This won't help.  The problem isn't looking up the IP address, it's passing the server name to the server via the [Server Name Indication part of the HTTPS protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).